# Entity Framework {"Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.\r\nParameter name: name"}

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

HI I am getting error when i try to save data to the table [ir].[InspectionQCExceptionRuleConfig]

> {"Specified argument was out of the range of valid
>   values.\r\nParameter name: name"}

I am not sure why, I am trying to save data. But, I am able to retrieve data from the models. I pasted the code, context and domain model. If any one knows about his . Pls tell me..

```
          public InspectionQCExceptionRuleConfig                         SaveInspectionQCRules
            (InspectionQCExceptionRuleConfig inspectionruleconfig)
            {
                if (inspectionruleconfig != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        using (InspRulesData ctx = new InspRulesData())
                        {
                            inspectionruleconfig = ctx.UpdateGraph(inspectionruleconfig, map => map);
                            //ctx.InspectionQCExceptionRuleConfigs.Add(inspectionruleconfig);
                            ctx.SaveChanges();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
                    {
                        Logging.LogError(ex);
                        throw;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Logging.LogError(ex);
                        throw;
                    }
                }

                return inspectionruleconfig;
            }
```

This is the Domain Model that is generated from Entity Framework

```
    namespace DomainModel.FSEntity.InspRules
    {
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
        using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
        using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;
        using CommonLib;

        [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("EF", "6.1.0")]
        [Table("ir.InspectionQCExceptionRuleConfig")]
        public partial class InspectionQCExceptionRuleConfig : BaseDomainModel
        {
            [Key]
            [StringLength(50)]
            [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
            public string ClientNumber { get; set; }

            public bool QCOrdered { get; set; }

            public bool DwellingType { get; set; }

            public bool VacantToOccupied { get; set; }

            public bool VacantToOccupiedWithActivePreservation { get; set; }

        }
    }
```

This is Context that is used by the Entity Framework to save the data o the table InspectionQCExceptionRuleConfig

```
        public partial class InspRulesData : CustomDbContext
        {



            public InspRulesData()
                : base("name=PlatformEntityData")
            {
                this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            }



 public virtual DbSet<InspectionQCExceptionRuleConfig>        InspectionQCExceptionRuleConfigs { get; set; }


            protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder     modelBuilder)
            {

                modelBuilder.Entity<InspectionQCExceptionRuleConfig>()
                    .Property(e => e.ClientNumber)
                    .IsVariableLength()
                    .IsUnicode(false);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What length does the ClientNumber string property has?

Comment: hi.. this is now solved. i changed the clientNumber property to int from string.  I am able to save data.

Answer (score 0):

It can also be caused by a misplaced [NotMapped] attribute in the Domain Model.